# find the number of skip rows between records

Tags: excel

I have requirement to get row number of next matching value. ie.

```
     Number 1   Number 2    Number 3    Number 4    Number 5    Number 6
      16    33  28  20  23  14
      13    12  27  29  2   32
      31    25  9   28  17  10
      11    22  14  3   18  13
      12    39  22  32  25  24
      37    40  33  18  9   3
       4    35  17  24  7   12
      16    3   38  8   17  24
```

now 16 is present in 7th row, and skipped rows are 6. 33 is present in 6th row so skipped rows are 5. Similarly 28 is present in 3rd row so skipped rows are 1. 
output will be :

```
6   4   1   19  10  2
```

assume that 20 and 23 found in 20th and 11th row respectively.Skipped rows = row number of next find of that number - present row number.

I am not able to form formula for this. Match should work I guess, but not sure.

Comment: MATCH does now work on 2 dimensional arrays. It works on a single row or a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this formula in the first cell:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$F$22)/($A$3:$F$22=A2),1) - ROW($A$3)
```

Then drag/copy across

[image]

If you want to drag down (put the results in columnar form):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$F$22)/($A$3:$F$22=INDEX($2:$2,ROW(1:1))),1) - ROW($A$3)
```

Put it in the first cell and drag/copy down.

[image]

Comment: I am amazed by the clever use of the AGGREGATE function. I must explore this function more!